# Where is source code of program dots (braille-program for blind people)?

Tags: installation, source-code

Where can I find the source code of dots?
It is given as program for blind people in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You can download from here..

[Dots 0.1](http://ftp.acc.umu.se/pub/GNOME/sources/dots/0.1/)